# Change tableView heightForFooterInSection depending on iOS version

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have noticed that the last row of my tableView is being cut off on the older iOS versions(<15.0). 
I decided to change the tableView footer depending on iOS version, so I want to hold the default footer if version is >= 15.0, but dont know how.

Here is the code:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return UIView()
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            //Problem is here. I must return something.
        } else {
            return 75 //This is ok
        }
    }
```

I have tried to return

- UIView().frame.size.height
- UITableView.automaticDimension

but it even makes more problems(returns 0).
Is there any other way to return the default footer on new iOS versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above code must be give you the default height

```
return myTableView.sectionFooterHeight
```

But , If you use footer view only for making some space to bottom side of the view , you dont need to add footer to your tableview , you can give some space to contentInset's bottom , this gonna fix the cut on last cell.

On viewdidload

```
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
       self.myTableView.contentInset.bottom = 75

    }
```

Comment: "return myTableView.sectionFooterHeight" works fine. thanks!